# allow page to only be so small horizontally

Tags: css

Is there a way to for a webpage to stop scaling down when someone is resizing the browser to a really small size.

so for example if the visible page is less than 500px turn on the scroll bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a minimum width on the body:

```
body {
    min-width:500px;
}
```